# Add values to chunked array values and output to table

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have and array with data:

```
$array = [
   0=>1
   1=>jon
   2=>jon@email.com
   3=>9-18-2018
   4=>2
   5=>doe
   6=>doe@email.com
   7=>9-18-2018
   8=>3
   9=>foo
   10=>foo@email.com
   11=>9-18-2018
]
```

Then I chunk this array and output as a table

```
    @foreach(array_chunk($array, 4) as $data)
     <tr>
     @foreach($data as $i => $chunked_data)
       <td>
          {{$data[$i]}}
       </td>
     @endforeach
     </tr>
   @endforeach
```

And I have a current output:

```
ID  Name     Email           Created at
1   Jon    jon@email.com      9-18-2018
2   Doe    doe@email.com      9-18-2018
3   Foo    foo@email.com      9-18-2018
```

What I need is to tell whitch record is what kind of data type by the 2nd array.

So the 1st one I created table from is chunked array:

```
  $array = [
   array[
      0=>1
      1=>Joe
      2=>joe@email.com
      3=>9-18-2018
   ]
     array[
      0=>1
      1=>Doe
      2=>doe@email.com
      3=>9-18-2018
   ]
     array[
      0=>1
      1=>Foo
      2=>foo@email.com
      3=>9-18-2018
   ]
]
```

2nd one is simple array:

```
$data_types = [
      0=>int
      1=>string
      2=>string
      3=>date
]
```

So my guess is that I would need to comine 1st and 2nd array something like this:

```
    $data_types = [
   0=>1 [int]
   1=>Joe [string]
   2=>joe@email.com [string]
   3=>9-18-2018 [date]
]
```

So my desired output is:

```
  ID        Name             Email                Created at
1(int)   Jon(string)    jon@email.com(string)      9-18-2018(date)
2(int)   Doe(string)    doe@email.com(string)      9-18-2018(date)
3(int)   Foo(string)    foo@email.com(string)      9-18-2018(date)
```

Keep in mind I have to achieve it by combining 2 arrays where one of them is pure data and the second one data types.

I am on laravel but plain php examples would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections) instead of pure arrays. Good Luck!

Comment: You don't need second array for types. just use `is_numeric == true`, `is_numeric == false` and `strtotime !== false`

Comment: Actually a very good suggestion...I`ll keep it in mind!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the index represented by `$i` in your code to get the type by referencing the second array :

```
@foreach(array_chunk($array, 4) as $data)
    <tr>
        @foreach($data as $i => $chunked_data)
            <td>
                {{$data[$i]}} {{$data_types[$i]}}
            </td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps.

Edit :

For the example in pure PHP :

```
$array = array(
    array(
        1,
        'Joe',
        'joe@email.com',
        '9-18-2018'
    ),
    array(
        2,
        'Doe',
        'doe@email.com',
        '9-18-2018',
    ),
    array(
        3,
        'Foo',
        'foo@email.com',
        '9-18-2018',
    )
);

$data_types = array(
    'int',
    'string',
    'string',
    'date'
);

foreach ($array as $chunked) {
    foreach ($chunked as $key => $data) {
        echo "{$data} {$data_types[$key]} | ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output :

> ```
> 1 int | Joe string | joe@email.com string | 9-18-2018 date |
> 2 int | Doe string | doe@email.com string | 9-18-2018 date |
> 3 int | Foo string | foo@email.com string | 9-18-2018 date |
> ```

Comment: This is the one! Thanks! How didn`t I thought about it!
Genius!
Marked as an answer!

Comment: Glad it helps. Good luck. ; )

Comment: it can use {{$chunked_data}} instead of {{$data[$i]}} just for lazy :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
0=>1
1=>jon
2=>jon@email.com
3=>9-18-2018
4=>2
5=>doe
6=>doe@email.com
7=>9-18-2018
8=>3
9=>foo
10=>foo@email.com
11=>9-18-2018
];
$data_types = [
  0=>int
  1=>string
  2=>string
  3=>date
];
foreach(array_chunk($array,4) as $data) {
     @foreach(array_chunk($array, 4) as $data)
 <tr>
 @foreach($data as $i => $chunked_data)
   <td>
      {{$chunked_data}}{{$data_types[$i]}}  //the order of the datas is certain so you can use the index directly
   </td>
 @endforeach
 </tr>
 @endforeach
}
```